# How to select and show thousands of records

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I have an SQLite query that, potentially, returns thousands of records. I need to show these records in a ListView but, obviously, I cannot show them all together. Which is the Android-way to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea to use pagination on your Sqlite query. If it really returns thousands of records as a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Endless Adapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless#readme) by Mark Murphy

Answer (score 0):

You can limit amount of items or make page-links (0-100, 101-200 etc).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll have a problem with thousands of records in a ListView unless you don't use a Cursor.